# MySQL sorted search results with JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple many-to-many query, which I made searchable:

```
SELECT article.*, COUNT(article.id) as hits
FROM article
JOIN article_tag ON article.id = article_tag.article_id
JOIN tag ON tag.id = article_tag.tag_id
WHERE (
    tag.title = "Foo"
    OR tag.title = "Bar"
    OR tag.title = "Foo Bar"
    OR article.title LIKE "%Foo%"
    OR article.title LIKE "%Bar%"
    OR article.title LIKE "%Foo Bar%"
)
AND (article.start <= NOW() OR article.start IS NULL)
AND (article.end > NOW() OR article.end IS NULL)
AND (article.type = 'USER')
AND article.enabled = 1
GROUP BY article.id
ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 0, 16
```

The searching works well enough, but the 'hits' reported can't be right and so the sorting is off.

EDIT: I think I can describe my problem a bit better now. If I change the first line to:

```
SELECT article.title, tag.title
```

and remove GROUP BY and ORDER BY, the result lists matching article titles with ALL referenced tag.titles – so the article with the most tags (matching the searchword or not) produces the most hits.

Comment: You shouldn't be `SELECT article.* ... GROUP BY article.id`. This will give you unpredictable results. Use ANSI standard `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Kermit: No. This is SQL standard as it is being interpreted by MySQL. The id uniquely identifys an article record, so you can access all its columns without aggregation.

Comment: @saibotd: You select articles and the count of their matching tags. What do you consider wrong about your results? Can you give examples?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Uh, *"The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."*

Comment: @Kermit: Yes, but as saibotd groups by **id**, all values are known. There cannot be two different names for example for the same id in articles, so the "randomly" chosen name will be the *one* existing name for the id.

Comment: I think I can describe my problem a bit better now: If I change the first line to:
SELECT article.title, tag.title
and remove GROUP BY, the result lists matching article titles with ALL referenced tag.titles – so the article with the most tags (matching the searchword or not) produces the most hits

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(article.id)` counts all records where article.id is not null. That's all records. So it is the same as `COUNT(*)`. You are counting the number of matching article tags.

If you want to count the number of articles, you can count distinct article ids:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT article.id)
```

Comment: Now 'hits' is always 1

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that you group by article.id. So of course my answer is useless. So far you grouped by article and counted the matching tags, and now you group by article and count 1 for each article. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try like this. give it a shot

```
SELECT article.*,X.hits
FROM article
JOIN article_tag ON article.id = article_tag.article_id
JOIN tag ON tag.id = article_tag.tag_id
JOIN 
(
select id,COUNT(id) as hits
from article
group by id
) X ON article.id = X.id
WHERE (
    tag.title in('Foo','Bar','Foo Bar')
    OR article.title LIKE "%Foo%"
    OR article.title LIKE "%Bar%"
    OR article.title LIKE "%Foo Bar%"
)
AND (article.start <= NOW() OR article.start IS NULL)
AND (article.end > NOW() OR article.end IS NULL)
AND (article.type = 'USER')
AND article.enabled = 1
ORDER BY X.hits DESC LIMIT 0, 16
```